# Rotating a video (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, mencoder

I have a video, shot on my android phone, which I want to rotate 90 degrees clockwise for computer viewing.  Here's what I expect should work:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -an -vcodec mpeg4 outfile.mp4
```

except that it gives me:

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect 
parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

The command `ffmpeg -codec` does produce a long list which includes `DEVSDT mpeg4 MPEG-4 part 2`

Then I experimented with

```
ffmpeg -vf "transpose=1″ -qscale=2 -i infile.mp4 outfile.mp4
```

but this seems to be an unfinished command, as all I get is a ">" symbol in my terminal.

I've also tried:

```
mencoder -fps 30000/1001 -ofps 30000/1001 -ovc lavc -vf rotate=1 -oac pcm
infile.mp4 -o outfile.mp4
```

which does work, but gives a very poor output - far worse than the input.

I can certainly view the video in the correct orientation:

```
mplayer -vo xv -vf rotate=1 infile.mp4
```

but I have as yet not found a way to write the rotated video to a file.  I have no experience at all with video coding, so any advice would be most welcome!

Comment: FWIW your first ffmpeg command is correct and should work (your second ffmpeg command is incorrect; `-vf` is an output option, so it shouldn't come before the input), so the problem might be with your video file. Does it play properly?

Comment: I have the same problem trying to convert or even just process an Android video made by CyanogenMod 10.1 on a SGS2 with Ubuntu-issue ffmpeg or avconv. I think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: I tried the first ffmpeg command on a few mp4 and mpg files I have here. It worked fine on both Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10. So as @evilsoup says it might be an issue with the specific video file you have.

Comment: Well, the video file plays fine, as I mentioned in the original post.  It plays even better with `mplayer -cache 8192 -ao sdl -vo gl -vf rotate=1 infile.mp4`.  I noticed when I played it earlier that it's quite big (512Mb, although only 4'30" long), and unless I'm careful with the sound and video codecs I get a `Your system is too SLOW to play this!` message, and the sound and video don't sync.  So maybe there is a problem with the file?  However, I *can* play it...

Comment: The complete ffmpeg console output for the first command will be useful if you're still interested in figuring out the issue...otherwise I can only guess. But my guess is you probably just need to remove the `=` signs.